# Finding time in ballistic problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The problem is like this:

> A bullet with mass 15g moving at a speed of 425 m/s is brought to a
> stop in 3.5 cm in a block of wood. Find the force on the bullet,
> assuming that it is constant.

So I know that: F = m*a

> m = 15
>
> g=9.81
>
> a = v/t
>
> v = 425 m/s
>
> t = ?

My question is: how to calculate time? My guess is, if the velocity is 425 m/s, and the bullet stumble upon a block of wood in 3.5 cm, I could transform the 425 m/s to cm/s (42500 cm) and then get the time, but what I get is a very tiny number, so I think I am doing it wrong...

Comment: The time should be a tiny number, and the acceleration a very big number.  Also, its easier to use work, W = F*d, where W is the initial kinetic energy of the bullet, d is the distance traveled.

Comment: F=W/d. Where W=1/2mv^2.

W=1354687.5 N
d=0.035m

F=1354687.5/0.035=38705357,14N

Just to be sure -- is this right? It's like, a huge number for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I ask exactly why you're bringing the gravitational constant *g* into this discussion?  I'm pretty sure the only "g" in this problem refers to "grams," NOT the gravitational constant.

That being said...if that's your stumbling block, I think this problem will start to make a lot more sense.  **HINT:** Think about what equations/physical principles you know that relate velocity, mass, distance, and force *without* needing to know any other quantities...

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I don't know why I wrote that there, I was just doing other problem and mixed all the thing!

Well, I did this, applying the formula that the guy from above suggested: F=W/d. Where W=1/2mv^2. W=1354687.5 N d=0.035m F=1354687.5/0.035=38705357,14N -- is this right, Steven?

Comment: Ron, I'm happy to answer general conceptual questions about physics or physics problems, but ultimately [this isn't a site where people will do your homework or check your answers for you](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).  The community would do more harm than good in helping you learn physics if we were to do that.

Comment: That being said:  a good first check for any physics problem is, "Do I understand the physical significance of the formulae I used and my final answer?"  A second easy check is, "Did I use the correct units at all stages of solving this problem?"  This latter question may prove particularly helpful for you.

Comment: Oops, I just saw the issue there... I used g instead of kg. The final result is 38705.35714. Well, I am very sorry about violating the rules, I won't do it again... and thanks everybody for helping me to resolve my problem! :)